# Can execute nagios ssh check manually but get 126/127 out of bounds error from nagios

Tags: ssh, nagios

I have the following service defined in my host definition:

```
define service {
    use                  generic-service
    host_name            myhost.com
    service_description  swapcheck
    check_command        check_ssh_swap
}
```

and the following in the commands.cfg:

```
define command {
    command_name check_ssh_swap
    command_line /home/nagios/bin/check_by_ssh -p port -H ip -C "/home/nagios/bin/check_swap -w 20% -c 5%"
}
```

both cfg files are loaded into nagios on load. And nagios -v /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg does not give back any errors.

When i try to execute the command

```
/home/nagios/bin/check_by_ssh -p port -H ip -C "/home/nagios/bin/check_swap -w 20% -c 5%"
```

with the nagios user directly, it works without problems, and I get my results back, but when nagios itself runs a scheduled check I always get

```
Return code of 126 for check of host 'host' was out of bounds
```

What am I missing here? Obviously all the paths, the keys, etc. are correct, otherwise I wouldnt be able to execute it manually without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, nagios doesnt like absolute paths. I switched back to $USER1$/... for the paths, and now it works?

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 126 from Nagios should mean that the the check was found, but it's not executable.  Maybe your script has incorrect world or other permissions so that Nagios cannot run it but you can?

Answer (score 0):

Your question didn't identify which OS platform you are using, but I'm going to guess `CentOS`.  If that's the case, then check whether `SELinux` is enabled and enforcing:
`#getenforce
Enforcing`

If so, you have a few options:

1. Put your scripts in the same location where other working scripts are found; you might need to do a `restorecon` so that your scripts get labelled appropriately for the directory
2. Learn how to use `audit2allow` to add to the valid locations for Nagios scripts

Another possibility that I wouldn't recommend at all but am mentioning for completeness only is to disable `SELinux`.  Think long and hard before doing this for anything other than a quick test.